# How to get content owner info for particular video via YouTube Partner API?

Tags: youtube-api

Is there a way to get content owner information (attribution) for particular video via YouTube Partner API?

For example, this video: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=I67cgXr6L6o&feature=c4-overview&list=UUGnjeahCJW1AF34HBmQTJ-Q is attributed to VEVO.

Is there a way to get that info somehow via API?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's possbible now:

https://developers.google.com/youtube/partner/docs/v1/ownership/

**[EDIT]**

I've used [this sample](https://developers.google.com/youtube/partner/code_samples/python)  to create the snipped below and succesfully got the assets content owner.
You will need setup your python enviromment and the clients_secrets.file correctly

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import httplib2
import os
import sys
import logging
import requests
import json
import time

from apiclient.discovery import build
from oauth2client.file import Storage
from oauth2client.client import flow_from_clientsecrets
from oauth2client.tools import argparser, run_flow
from symbol import for_stmt







# The CLIENT_SECRETS_FILE variable specifies the name of a file that contains
# the OAuth 2.0 information for this application, including its client_id and
# client_secret. You can acquire an OAuth 2.0 client ID and client secret from
# the Google Developers Console at
# https://console.developers.google.com/.
# Please ensure that you have enabled the YouTube Data API for your project.
# For more information about using OAuth2 to access the YouTube Data API, see:
#   https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/authentication
# For more information about the client_secrets.json file format, see:
#   https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/python/guide/aaa_client_secrets
CLIENT_SECRETS_FILE = "client_secrets.json"

# This variable defines a message to display if the CLIENT_SECRETS_FILE is
# missing.
MISSING_CLIENT_SECRETS_MESSAGE = """
WARNING: Please configure OAuth 2.0

To make this sample run you will need to populate the client_secrets.json file
found at:

   %s

with information from the Developers Console
https://console.developers.google.com/

For more information about the client_secrets.json file format, please visit:
https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/python/guide/aaa_client_secrets
""" % os.path.abspath(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), CLIENT_SECRETS_FILE))

YOUTUBE_SCOPES = (
  # This OAuth 2.0 access scope allows for read-only access to the authenticated
  # user's account, but not other types of account access.
  "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube.readonly",
  # This OAuth 2.0 scope grants access to YouTube Content ID API functionality.
  "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtubepartner")
YOUTUBE_API_SERVICE_NAME = "youtube"
YOUTUBE_API_VERSION = "v3"
YOUTUBE_PARTNER_API_SERVICE_NAME = "youtubePartner"
YOUTUBE_PARTNER_API_VERSION = "v1"

KEY = "USE YOUR KEY"


# Authorize the request and store authorization credentials.
def get_authenticated_services(args):
  flow = flow_from_clientsecrets(CLIENT_SECRETS_FILE, scope=" ".join(YOUTUBE_SCOPES), message=MISSING_CLIENT_SECRETS_MESSAGE)

  storage = Storage("%s-oauth2.json" % sys.argv[0])
  credentials = storage.get()

  if credentials is None or credentials.invalid:
    credentials = run_flow(flow, storage, args)

  youtube = build(YOUTUBE_API_SERVICE_NAME, YOUTUBE_API_VERSION,  http=credentials.authorize(httplib2.Http()))

  youtube_partner = build(YOUTUBE_PARTNER_API_SERVICE_NAME, YOUTUBE_PARTNER_API_VERSION, http=credentials.authorize(httplib2.Http()))

  return (youtube, youtube_partner)


def get_content_owner_id(youtube_partner):
  content_owners_list_response = youtube_partner.contentOwners().list(fetchMine=True).execute()

  return content_owners_list_response["items"][0]["id"]
#def

def claim_search(youtube_partner, content_owner_id, _videoId):

  video_info = get_video_info(_videoId)  
  print '\n---------- CLAIM SEARCH LIST - VIDEO (',video_info['title'],') ID: (',_videoId,')'
  claims = youtube_partner.claimSearch().list( videoId=_videoId, onBehalfOfContentOwner=content_owner_id).execute()
  print ' --- CLAIMS: ',claims

  if claims['pageInfo']['totalResults'] < 1:
    print " --- DOESN'T HAVE CLAIMS"
    return

  assetId = claims['items'][0]['assetId']
  print ' --- ASSET ID: ', assetId

  ownershipHistory = youtube_partner.ownershipHistory().list(assetId=assetId, onBehalfOfContentOwner=content_owner_id).execute()
  print ' --- OWNERSHIP HISTORY: ', ownershipHistory  

  contentOwnerId = ownershipHistory['items'][0]['origination']['owner']
  print ' --- CONTENT OWNER ID: ', contentOwnerId

  contentOwners = youtube_partner.contentOwners().get(contentOwnerId=contentOwnerId, onBehalfOfContentOwner=content_owner_id).execute()
  print ' --- CONTENT OWNERS: ', contentOwners


def get_video_info(videoId):
  r = requests.get("https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?id="+videoId+"&part=id,snippet,contentDetails,status,statistics,topicDetails,recordingDetails&key="+KEY)
  content = r.content

  content = json.loads(content)
  return content['items'][0]['snippet']






if __name__ == "__main__":
  args = argparser.parse_args()
  (youtube, youtube_partner) = get_authenticated_services(args)

  #video id's. Ex: "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lgSLz5FeXUg"
  videos = ['I67cgXr6L6o', 'lgSLz5FeXUg']

  content_owner_id = get_content_owner_id(youtube_partner)

  for vid in videos :
      claim_search(youtube_partner, content_owner_id, vid)
      time.sleep(0.5)
```

The (censored) proof :
[image]

Comment: are you sure that this is not just for the assets owned by the user himself? i wanted a way to get ownership (attribution) of arbitrary youtube video.

Comment: @MilovanZogovic, added a code solution to my answer

Comment: AWESOME! I've just tried it out (rewriting it to ruby) and it works like a charm! THANKS!!

Comment: For some videos, it gives me multiple OwnershipHistory records, and it is hard to determine which one is the proper (e.g. this video: My2FRPA3Gf8). Do you have any clues/guides on how to decipher api response and pick the proper ownership record?

Comment: For DfwJA0f0UTg, i get the "SME" as owner, but when I look at that video youtube page, there is `<meta name=attribution content=vevo/>` tag indicating that the video is attributed to vevo instead.. This is all too confusing :)

Comment: @MilovanZogovic: looks like the last item in OwnershipHistory is the current owner. I have no official confirmation but seems logical to me because the last item is Vevo, and now the video is displayed by a Vevo account, and not SME (Sony Music Entertainment).

Comment: sometimes it is last.. but sometimes it is not. More confusingly if you run DfwJA0f0UTg video through the script, you'll get SME as owner, but it is clearly VEVO content. I'll need to dig deeply into this and try to understand the Ownership records. Thank you again for pointing me in this direction - its a good start.

Comment: In my opinion this answer can't be correct in case the claim `claims['items'][0]` is not made by the video's own content owner. (you know, there are third party claims)

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to check other people's ownership or management rights on a video or channel. YouTube deliberately avoids that.

Answer (score 0):

While `ownershipHistory` works, I saw `GET https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/partner/v1/assets?id=[multiple asset ids]` also worked when it's called with `fetchOwnership=effective` option

https://developers.google.com/youtube/partner/docs/v1/assets/list

Comment: Now I see this question is about finding content owner name from a video id. In that case, I'm not sure it's possible. I thought it's about finding a content owner from asset ids because the selected answer was looking for claims to the video first and get asset id from a claim and then get the content owner from there.